# php if statement equals this then display this

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

**Here is my issue... See my details below:**

mysamplesite.com has a form on it that requires a drop-down selection of a product, there are 4 products.

Once a product is selected and the form is submitted it passes that product form value to the next page.
On that next page I need to know the "*if statement*" that would display the product selected from the previous page because tehre are 4 products.

**This is what is used to capture the value:**

```
<?php $id = $_GET['product1']; echo $id;?>
```

I just need to know the "if statement" to use so I can display the different products on the next page. A product would be displayed depending upon which product was selected. So "if it's this then display this"...

I've searched stackoverflow have haven't really found an example of what i'm looking for. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: Where are these products stored? In a database? If so, just grab it (or compare it) from there via the id.

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation for `if` statement examples? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php. SO is not suitable for learning the basics of a language.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Can you show your form that will be processed, and perhaps (as @webbiedave asked above) tell us how you store your product information to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
if($id == "option1") {
    // do this
}
else if($id == "option2") {
    // do this
}
else if($id == "option3") {
    // do this
}
else{
    // do this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    switch($_GET['product1']) {
       case 'option 1' :
           echo "option 1";
       break;
       case 'option 2' :
           echo "option 2";
       break;
       case 'option 3' :
           echo "option 3";
       break;
       case 'option 4' :
           echo "option 4";
       break;
       default:
           //no option selected ?
    }
?>
```